# PPTP VPN randomly disconnects

Tags: network-manager, 20.04, vpn, pptp, pptpd

My **PPTP** VPN works fine on Windows and Android. 
On Android and Windows, no specific configuration is needed only I need to check **PPP encryption(MPPE)**.

But on Ubuntu 20.04 it disconnects randomly after a period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Ubuntu 14 pptp client disconnects frequently](http://poth-chola.blogspot.com/2015/11/ubuntu-14-pptp-client-disconnects.html).

I had to use on the client.

```
sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 mtu 1400
sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
```

This could be investigated by reading syslog errors:

```
pouria@pouria-pc:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep pptp | grep long
May 31 09:36:11 pouria-pc pptp[18156]: nm-pptp-service-18147 warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:352]: short read (-1): Message too long
May 31 09:47:14 pouria-pc pptp[18617]: nm-pptp-service-18609 warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:352]: short read (-1): Message too long
May 31 09:57:18 pouria-pc pptp[19439]: nm-pptp-service-19430 warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:352]: short read (-1): Message too long
May 31 10:07:21 pouria-pc pptp[20790]: nm-pptp-service-20781 warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:352]: short read (-1): Message too long
May 31 10:17:57 pouria-pc pptp[21003]: nm-pptp-service-20994 warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:352]: short read (-1): Message too long
May 31 11:16:36 pouria-pc pptp[23730]: nm-pptp-service-23718 warn[decaps_gre:pptp_gre.c:352]: short read (-1): Message too long
```

By setting `mtu` we are telling the `wlan` to use smaller messages.

I wonder why users of other operating systems don't have to configure their WLAN message size to use the simplest form of VPN.

### update

### To do it permanently

Find your device's interface name `wlan0...` by `ifconfig`.

Create the file `/etc/network/if-up.d/ppp` with the following content:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo ifconfig wlp0s20f3 mtu 1400
sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
```

Use `chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/ppp` to make it executable. It runs on every connect and disconnect.

Comment: Thank you, I searched a lot, and all of the answers on the internet wasn't solved, but this saved me!

Answer (score 0):

I use your answer, and answer it to solve the question about **Set the MTU permanently**:

[I found this link (for permanent set the MTU)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207020/how-do-i-persistently-set-the-mtu-for-a-pptp-vpn-connection-in-ubuntu/549679#549679)

We **make a script** in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and call it `set-pptp.sh`, this script will be called whenever a link is trying to get up.

Now inside this file we insert these lines:

[We are checking the current interface that is trying to get up, **if it's a VPN, we set its MTU to 1300 and if not we set its MTU to 1400**]

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
   ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
fi

if [ "$IFACE" = "wlp3s0" ]; then
   ifconfig wlp3s0 mtu 1400
fi
```

Now we need to **make it executable**:

```bsh
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/set-pptp.sh
```

**Last Step (Important)**:

If you are using a graphical network manager, those that are in KDE, Gnome, etc ..., you need to do this too:

**Open this file**: `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01-ifupdown`, in my computer, its name is 01-ifupdown, maybe in yours it has other names, open it.

Find the line that has something like this:

```bsh
if [ "$2" = "vpn-up" ] || [ "$2" = "vpn-down" ]; then
```

**Change it to this:**

```bsh
if [ "$2" = "vpn-up" ] || [ "$2" = "vpn-down" ]; then
    ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
   ADDRESS_FAMILIES=""
fi
```

Done, you have a permanently MTU settings now.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I added my own shortcut version which is easier to do on each Ubuntu installation.